# How to update ticket description in zendesk from application

Tags: android, zendesk

i'm trying to update description of already created ticket from android application ,please tell me how it is possible to update already created ticket data

**i tried this url:**

> https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/79.json \
>         -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>         -d '{"ticket": {"status": "open", "comment": { "body": "The smoke is very colorful.", "author_id": 494820284 }}}' \
>         -v -u xxx@xxx.com/token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -X PUT

Comment: Hey, are you using Zendesk's mobile SDK or are you trying to use the Rest API?

Comment: @Sebastian i was using rest api in their doc i found that only agent can edit ticket data through api,can end user can change their ticket data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you're able to update the description, per [Zendesk's API documentation](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/tickets.html#description-and-first-comment) -

Description and first comment

```
When creating a ticket, use the comment key to set the ticket description, which is also the first comment. Example:

{"ticket": {"subject": "My printer is on fire!", "comment": {"body": "The smoke is very colorful."}}}

Note: Do not use the description key to set the first comment. The key is for reading purposes only. While it's possible to use the key to set the first comment, the functionality has limitations and is provided to support existing implementations.
```

As for end-user updating the ticket: there is a very limited number of updates the end-user can make, such as adding a comment and changing the status of a ticket.  There may be a couple others, but things like custom fields, ticket type, group, and assignee cannot be changed by end-user.